# Getting entire values from a custom resource file Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-xml, android-resources

Lets say I have some custom resource file called categories.xml in values folder which is as follows

```
<resources>

<string name="name_a" >A
</string>
<string name="name_b" >B
</string></resources>
```

How can I obtain only A and B as a string array in code with out getting values from string.xml?

Note: In the code it has no idea that How many values or what values exists in the resource file.

Thank You !

Comment: use [string array](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#string-array-element)?

Comment: first you said obtain only A and B then you said you no idea how many values. Did you know what you are asking? `String s = getString(R.string.name_a);`

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Using string arrays is the solution. Thanks bogdan. There at the code user need not to specify the name. we can get the whole bundle of strings.

Answer (score 1):

To read the resources, you can:

- Use the [`Resources.getString(id)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getString%28int%29) method, to get the strings themselves: `getResources().getString(R.string.name_a);`
- Use the [`Resources.getXml(id)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getXml%28int%29) method, to get the entire XML file and read the strings yourself.
- Use the [`Resources.openRawResource(id)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource%28int%29) method, read the entire file as a string and search for anything you want inside.